# Searching for an Example

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be a set and A be an algebra over X. Also, let μ be a finite measure on A, and μ* be the corresponding outer measure, defined on all subsets of X. Can someone give an example of a subset Y of X, for which μ* (Y) + μ* (X - Y) = μ(X), but μ* (Y∩K) + μ* ((X - Y)∩K) ≠ μ* (K) for at least one K⊆X? Also, does there exist an example of a finite (X,A,μ) (A is an algebra on X), for which the sets {Y⊆X :  μ* (Y) + μ* (X - Y) = μ(X)} and {Y⊆X : μ* (Y∩K) + μ* ((X - Y)∩K) = μ* (K) ∀ K⊆X} are equal?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)